# Separating Categorical Data Variable into Multiple Variables

Tags: r, strsplit

I have this type of data (name: pmt4651) and want to separate and keep only the answers as independent elements (maybe in individual columns so that I can create a function to count and analyze them):

> 2
>                                                                                                                {"Q0":"An abstract musical score.\nAn abandoned set of flagpoles.\nA highway with a road sign to its right.\nA shelf protruding from a wall.\n"}
>
> 3
>                                                                                         {"Q0":"An abstract flower.\nA setup diagram for an orchestral percussionist.\nA seating chart diagram for a wedding reception.\nA magic wand.\nA lollipop."}

I tried the `separate` and the `strsplit` function and to separate them by the "\n" sign but so far I failed. For the `strsplit` function I received an error with the note `non-character argument`. 
With this: `sub(pattern = "{"Q0":"", replacement = "", x = pmt4651)`

I tried to remove the symbols at the beginning of each row- because this is information I don't need. However, this failed as well.

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

Comment: What's the format of your data?

Comment: It's a csv file and I stored the data as a data frame. Before storing it as a data frame R responded with "factor" when I asked for the class

Comment: Try using `as.character()`

Comment: that worked! At least i don't get an error now anymore. However it doesn't separate the answers - I think I can't manipulate/arrange them because they are captured in the curly brackets and quotation marks. With former data I was able to remove them with the sub(pattern...) function (as mentioned above) but this time it doesn't work

Comment: when you read the data try `read.csv("stuff.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE) ` it will prevent the factoization.

Comment: hm, unfortunately R still gives me the same output with that code

Comment: If you can, do `dput(head(yourImportedData))` and add that to the above so we can help better.